# How can I use Google assistant to navigate to a contact?

Tags: contacts, google-maps, google-assistant

I have a contact with an address. If I type in the name in Google Maps then it suggests the contacts address for navigation. However using Google assistant it doesn't work. I tried the typical phrases like "route to John" or "Navigate to John" (in German).  I have Android 8.1 and live in Germany.

Comment: Not possible apparently .  See [Google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/MG_KwGNcRXA;context-place=topicsearchin/websearch/category$3Aandroid|sort:relevance|spell:false). You can follow that for future

Comment: @beeshyams: Thanks, I posted my data there and hope for an answer soon.